# How can I disable the strerr logging output from FOP?

Tags: java, apache-fop

How would I disable the logging output (usually sent to stderr) that FOP automatically generates when processing an FO file?

I've tried putting a `log4j.properties` file in the classpath, changing the log-level for `org.apache.fop` but this hasn't worked.

Answer (score 7):

This maybe late, but in version 1.1 your can create a class that implements `EventListener`. In `processEvent` you can simply ignore any messages you don't want to see.

From [FOP Docs](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/events.html):

```
import org.apache.fop.events.Event;
import org.apache.fop.events.EventFormatter;
import org.apache.fop.events.EventListener;
import org.apache.fop.events.model.EventSeverity;

/** A simple event listener that writes the events to stdout and stderr. */
public class SysOutEventListener implements EventListener {

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    public void processEvent(Event event) {
        String msg = EventFormatter.format(event);
        EventSeverity severity = event.getSeverity();
        if (severity == EventSeverity.INFO) {
            System.out.println("[INFO ] " + msg);
        } else if (severity == EventSeverity.WARN) {
            System.out.println("[WARN ] " + msg);
        } else if (severity == EventSeverity.ERROR) {
            System.err.println("[ERROR] " + msg);
        } else if (severity == EventSeverity.FATAL) {
            System.err.println("[FATAL] " + msg);
        } else {
            assert false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
StreamSource strm = new StreamSource(new File(fo));
OutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(pdfName)));
Fop fop = _fopFactory.newFop(org.apache.xmlgraphics.util.MimeConstants.__Fields.MIME_PDF, outStream);
FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fop.getUserAgent();
foUserAgent.getEventBroadcaster().addEventListener(new SysOutEventListener());
```

Comment: this only adds an additional listener, it does not prevent stderr output.

Comment: @ths - Read my response. I say nothing about disabling. I say they "can create a class that implements EventListener. In processEvent you can simply ignore any messages you don't want to see."

Comment: i know what you wrote, but have you read the question?

Comment: @ths I provided a solution to a problem. Perhaps its not the solution for you, but may be for others.

Answer (score 2):

I found a hint in the fop documentation: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/embedding.html#basic-logging saying "We've switched [...] to Jakarta Commons Logging". Your `log4j.properties` will probably have no effect, because they are using commons logging.

This works in my case:

```
<logger name="org.apache.fop">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="logfile" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</logger>
```

Check your commons logging configuration, whether the discovery process can find log4j (
http://commons.apache.org/logging/guide.html#Configuration )

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger log = (org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger) LogFactory.getLog("org.apache.fop");

log.getLogger().setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.FATAL);
```

Comment: Works for me. +1 for including fully qualified class names.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know FOP but you can always redirect the STDERR to where ever you like with code like the following:

```
File errDumpFile = new File("Path\to\a\File")
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(errDumpFile);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
System.setErr(ps);
```

Note: you don't have to redirect to a file, the `PrintStream` can take any `OutputStream`.